# Data Read From File Not Working in Bubble Sort Method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods, text-files

so I've been trying to read data from a file into arrays and use a bubble sort to organize the data. I need a method for both the file read and the bubble sort. I don't know how I would get the data to read into the bubble sort, in addition to the fact that my code never reaches the bubble sort. Here is my code:

```
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    //Error trap
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.println ("Which sorting method would you like to use? (Type bubble for Bubble Sort or insert for Insertion Sort)");
        String sort = in.nextLine ();

        if (sort.equalsIgnoreCase ("bubble"))
        {
            bubble (args, args, args, args, args);
        }
        if (sort.equalsIgnoreCase ("insert"))
        {
            insert ();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println ("Please enter the correct data.");
        }
    }
}

public static void readfile () throws IOException
{
    //Declaring variables
    String fileName, fnameTemp, lnameTemp, cityTemp, ageTemp, emailTemp;
    int howMany = 0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println ("Enter the file name:");
    fileName = in.nextLine ();

    BufferedReader input;
    input = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (fileName));

    fnameTemp = input.readLine ();
    lnameTemp = input.readLine ();
    cityTemp = input.readLine ();
    ageTemp = input.readLine ();
    emailTemp = input.readLine ();

    //Reading data until end of the file to determine the number of records
    while (fnameTemp!= null)
    {
        howMany++;
        fnameTemp = input.readLine ();
        lnameTemp = input.readLine ();
        cityTemp = input.readLine ();
        ageTemp = input.readLine ();
        emailTemp = input.readLine ();
    }

    input.close ();
    input = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (fileName));

    String fname [] = new String [howMany];
    String lname [] = new String [howMany];
    String city [] = new String [howMany];
    String age [] = new String [howMany];
    String email [] = new String [howMany];

    for (int count = 0; count < howMany; count++)
    {
        fname [count] = input.readLine ();
        lname [count] = input.readLine ();
        city [count] = input.readLine ();
        age [count] = input.readLine ();
        email [count] = input.readLine ();
    }

    input.close ();

    for (int count = 0; count < howMany; count++)
    {
        //System.out.println (fname [count]);
        //System.out.println (lname [count]);
        //System.out.println (city [count]);
        //System.out.println (age [count]);
        //System.out.println (email [count]);
    }
}

public static void bubble (String fname [], String lname [], String city [], String age [], String email []) throws IOException
{
    String temp, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5;
    int howMany = 0;

    readfile ();

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println ("Which item would you like to sort?");
    System.out.println ("Type firstname, lastname, city, age, or email to choose.");
    String item = in.nextLine ();

    if (item.equalsIgnoreCase ("firstname"))
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= howMany; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < howMany; j++)
                {
                    if (fname [j].compareToIgnoreCase (fname [j + 1]) > 0)
                    {
                    temp = fname [j];
                    fname [j] = fname [j + 1];
                    fname [j + 1] = temp;

                    temp2 = lname [j];
                    lname [j] = lname [j + 1];
                    lname [j + 1] = temp2;

                    temp3 = city [j];
                    city [j] = city [j + 1];
                    city [j + 1] = temp3;

                    temp4 = age [j];
                    age [j] = age [j + 1];
                    age [j + 1] = temp4;

                    temp5 = email [j];
                    email [j] = email [j + 1];
                    email [j + 1] = temp5;

                    System.out.println (fname [i]);
                    System.out.println (lname [i]);
                    System.out.println (city [i]);
                    System.out.println (age [i]);
                    System.out.println (email [i]);

                    System.out.println ("Sorted");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Just a note, it never gets past for (int i = 1; i <= howMany; i++)

My text file has a piece of data on every line going from first name, last name,  city, age and email.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, the reason it doesn't get past that point is because you initialize howMany to 0 and never change it, so the for loop initializes i to 1, which is greater than howMany, and then never executes.  I am also a bit confused because you say you want to use the data from the file, but then in main you pass the command line arguments to your function.  To fix the

I would personally use a .csv file to store the info too as they are easier to work with in my opinion.

Anyways, here's some code (using .csv, but it would be pretty easy to modify for whatever), that will get the file data and pass it to bubble sort.  I didn't do anything with the sorting method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String[] users = readFile("C:\\Users\\vikin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\data.csv");
        for(String s : users) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        bubble(users);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String[] readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        //String[] split = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
        //Collections.addAll(data, split);
        data.add(scanner.nextLine());
    }

    String[] users = new String[data.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        users[i] = data.get(i);
    }

    return users;
}

public static void bubble (String[] data) throws IOException
{
    String temp, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5;

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    String[] fname = new String[data.length];
    String[] lname = new String[data.length];
    String[] city = new String[data.length];
    String[] age = new String[data.length];
    String[] email = new String[data.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        String[] s = data[i].split(",");
        fname[i] = s[0];
        lname[i] = s[1];
        city[i] = s[2];
        age[i] = s[3];
        email[i] = s[4];
    }
    //rest of sort here
}
```

Comment: It's a pretty bad idea to parse CSV with `split` since CSV normally supports quotes, escaped quotes, etc. If you're going to use CSV, use a library.